# I have error with eslint , I am tryin to create react app and I got this error

Tags: reactjs, eslint

Oops! Something went wrong! :(

> ESLint: 7.32.0
>
> ESLint couldn't find the config "react-app" to extend from. Please
> check that the name of the config is correct.

The config "react-app" was referenced from the config file in "/home/runner/work/Math-magic/Math-magic/my-app/package.json".

If you still have problems, please stop by https://eslint.org/chat/help to chat with the team.

Comment: Could you post the file where this is referenced? You can try reinstalling the config (npm i eslint-config-react-app)

Comment: Do you understand eslint? You now have a nice link to go study up on the issue here.  I don't see how we can "guess" your error here.